# Node.js Express.js PayPal integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal

I need to integrate PayPal into my website, and I have integrated it, but I don't now how to put *total* in paypal syntax, which is in my code. In **app.js**, it creates routes for my page in website. In **cart.js**, I create the cart and a function where I calculate the total.

**app.js**

```js
app.post('/pay', function(  data,req, res)  {
    
 

  console.log(total);
  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                // "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                // "sku": "001",
                "price": "45.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": total,
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
  
};
```

**cart.js**

```js
function showCart(data) {
  let out = '<table class="table table-striped table-cart"><tbody>';
  let total = 0;
  for (let key in cart) {
    out += `<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="/goods?id=${key}">${data[key]['name']}</a></tr>`;
    out += `<tr><td><i class="far fa-minus-square cart-minus" data-goods_id="${key}"></i></td>`;
    out += `<td>${cart[key]}</td>`;
    out += `<td><i class="far fa-plus-square cart-plus" data-goods_id="${key}"></i></td>`;
    out += `<td>${formatPrice(data[key]['cost'] * cart[key])} lei </td>`
    out += '</tr>';
    total += cart[key] * data[key]['cost'];
  }
  out += `<tr><td colspan="3">Total: </td><td>${formatPrice(total)}lei</td></tr>`;
  out += '</tbody></table>';
  document.querySelector('#cart-nav').innerHTML = out;
  document.querySelectorAll('.cart-minus').forEach(function (element) {
    element.onclick = cartMinus;
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('.cart-plus').forEach(function (element) {
    element.onclick = cartPlus;
  });
}
```

**Image**

[image]

**How can I integrate the total in my website from card.js**?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the server-side demo pattern of PayPal Checkout as a base:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: friend give me your contact, and i write you message, and pls help me with you have time